# How can I create an expandable and scrollable list?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to accomplish following:

A `JPanel` (representing the container) including multiple `JPanels` which are including a `JButton` which - upon clicking - reveals another `JPanel` associated with the clicked `JButton`. When one of the `JPanels` expand, the other entries underneath it should dynamically change their position too. There should also be a scrolling functionality since each button has a fixed size (specified before launching the program) and it can't just change the button size to not overflow the `JPanel` with buttons. These overflows are typical here.

It should look something like this:

[image: what the result should be]

In the following I am going through my code I already wrote which has some minor problems. For the sake of simple program reproduction, I put all my code into one `TextGui` class and every code block within this post just adds to that file.

1. The `TestGui` `JFrame` and entry into the program, nothing peculiar about it.

```
public class TestGui extends JFrame {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestGui::new);
    }

    public TestGui() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new ListPanelTest());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

2. The `JPanel` which is basically the container for all the expandable `JPanels`. Has the task to store the panels inside, so that the `MouseWheelListener` can move them all. The movement works fine until an entry is expanded, the view snaps back to the top, but should of course be the same as before.
   There is also the problem of resizing. Resizing the window reveals a fatal flaw, the `JButtons` are not directly underneath each other but are rather separated by white spaces where `JPanels` *could* be revealed.

```
class ListPanelTest extends JPanel {
    String[] entryTexts = {"dropdown1:content1", "dropdown2:content2", "dropdown3:content3"};
    ArrayList<EntryListPanelTest> entryPanels;

    public ListPanelTest(){
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        entryPanels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String entryText: entryTexts) {
            EntryListPanelTest entryListPanel = new EntryListPanelTest(entryText);
            entryPanels.add(entryListPanel);
            add(entryListPanel);
        }

        addMouseWheelListener(e -> {
            for (EntryListPanelTest entryPanel : entryPanels) {
                entryPanel.setLocation(entryPanel.getX(), entryPanel.getY() - e.getWheelRotation() * 20);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

3. The last class should be self-explanatory. A `JButton` reveals (and hides) a `JPanel`. The only interesting part is the `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `BorderLayout.CENTER`. They are important to convey the `LayoutManager` in which order and where to position both entries.

```
class EntryListPanelTest extends JPanel {
    public EntryListPanelTest(String entryText){
        String[] entryTextSplit = entryText.split(":");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton(entryTextSplit[0]);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(entryTextSplit[1]);
        label.setVisible(false);

        add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button.addActionListener(e -> label.setVisible(!label.isVisible()));
    }
}
```

The program is already pretty close to what I am trying to archive but the points elucidated in 2 are really important. How can I stop snapping to the top upon reveal of some content? How can I get rid of spacing between unrevealed `JButtons` if the size is not the `packed()` size? And is there maybe an even simpler way to this behavior (but still without an additional library)?

Comment: This probably isn't helpful at all, but it sounds like you are trying to recreate a tree diagram. EDIT - specifically, a JTree -- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTree.html

Comment: @davidalayachew a `JTree` is not really what I am looking for since I want to change the GUI afterwards and add more elements to the expanded `JPanel`

Comment: Which is completely understandable. I figured that is why it wouldn't work. I will try my best to type up an answer to this. One sec.

Comment: Is there are a reason why you added scrolling functionality without using JScrollPane? Not having a default scrollbar is making this a lot harder to do

Comment: No, there isnt really a reason, but I definitely don't want to see a slider. I just assumed adding a JScrollPane will also add a Slider

Comment: Hmmmmm, this is getting very tricky then. Long story short, you are definitely not using the API the way it was meant to be. You essentially want all of the benefits of a JScrollPane, but with the scroll bars being invisible. And that is causing problems because the components you are using (your layout manager, your JFrame, etc) are making assumptions for you, thinking that you are using them correctly. As a result, it does things like move the view position back to the top. I'm not sure I can help, but I will try some more.

Comment: Why are you so opposed to having a Slider? Truthfully, what you are trying to do goes against the typical user experience. Is there a reason that you don't want to see one?

Comment: The OP is trying to create an [accordion component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)).  JavaFX has an accordion component.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yes, but I don’t want to build an entire GUI with a system I never used before for a project

Comment: @davidalayachew the main reason for all these things is that I don’t like the typical look of Java Swing components and I want to customize my own. I just thought building a simple Test class for Stackoverflow without the information baked into it makes things easier. I will happily use the JScollPane if there is a way of overwriting it’s default look and rather have my own. I did a quick google search and it looks like you can, so okay

Comment: Oh, then yes, fixing the L&F is very easy to do. Comparatively, what you are trying to do here is like trying to swim upstream. Yes, I would avoid doing it this way if you are willing, and instead, focus on making your own custom look and feel. That is how most developers do it. A lot of GUI's made in Swing add a few custom components, and then completely overhaul the L&F to be what they want. Sounds like you are going down the same path.

Comment: And btw, Java comes pre-built with a couple L&F's. In the name of saving work, I would try them out before going any further.